# Excel file located on file server is saying it is opened and locked by a user but it really isn't

Tags: windows, file-sharing

There is an Excel file that is on our file server which when you try to open is saying it is locked and in use by an individual whose computer is shutdown and isn't logged in from anywhere else.

Has anybody come across this before? What do I need to do to get the file server to recognize that the file isn't actually in use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Computer Manger on the server, expand Shared Folders and then Open Files.  There you should be able to remove the lock.